# How to target specific frameworks when building .Net MAUI app?

Tags: .net-6.0, maui

I am new to .Net Maui. I have a lot of experience with Xamarin. I am using Rider for MacOS.

I am attempting to build a .Net MAUI Application for iOS and Android. I've successfully created a .Net Maui template (from Rider). Since Android is easier to build and deploy, I want to start there. However, when I created a new MAUI template and clicked "Run" in my IDE, I got a bunch of iOS and MacOS specific errors. Through much weeping and gnashing of teeth, I discovered that this was because my project's `TargetFrameworks` were set in the MyApp.csproj file like so:

`<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>`

I discovered that removing all target frameworks (below) except for `net6.0-android` resulted in the successful build and deployment of the MAUI app! Hooray!

`<TargetFramework>net6.0-android</TargetFramework>`

The problem with this solution is that I now *can't* build my MAUI app for iOS or MacOS. Is there a way to say:

```
1. If the user is trying to build an android app => TargetFramework = net6.0-android
2. If the user is trying to build an iOS app => TargetFramework = net6.0-ios
3. etc.
```

In other words: "I'm only trying to build Android right now. Don't worry about compiling things for any other platform / framework. I may want to build for a different platform / framework later! Just not right now"

Answer (score 1):

You can *almost* get this effect (tested in VS 2022 Preview, on Windows PC):

- Rt-click project / properties / Application.
- Notice sections "iOS Targets", "Android Targets", "Windows Targets".
- Each has a checkbox "Enable targeting of the ... platform". Use those.

This doesn't *automatically* change as you change target. But its easier than editing .csproj.

Comment: I do not see iOS Targets, Android Targets, or Windows Targets on either Rider or Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you on Mac?  For now, might have no choice but to edit .csproj.

Comment: I am on a Mac. Maybe that is the difference. Am I thinking about this problem wrong? Is MAUI not intended to do what I'm asking for here?

Comment: Your thinking is correct. Mac IDEs don't yet have some refinements. Even Windows version didn't have this until recently. Indeed, it is an annoying omission. The whole concept of "multi-targetting" - having one project that can build for multiple platforms - is still fairly new.

Comment: I updated my question to include that I am on MacOS. Thank you for your suggestions Steve!

Comment: There might be a way to do this via additional configurations. Use Configuration Manager to copy "Debug" configuration to "ios_only". Save. Examine .csproj. Now has line `<Configurations>Debug;Release;ios_only</Configurations>`. There should be some way to use the currently selected "configuration" inside a `<TargetFrameworks Condition="...` element. You would move `net6.0-ios` inside that element. I don't know what the correct build-time `$(somebuildpropertynamehere)` term is, for `Configuration=ios-only`.